# Get the command link clicked in adf?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have 50 different command links on a jsff page. I want to get the commandlink clicked in the backing bean? How to do this? I just have to use one single method in the backing bean

Comment: Why would 50 different links invoke the same actionListener? Even if they invoke, is the action same for all the 50 links? If the action is not same then do you use a switch to tackle which action to perform? Keeping separate action for each link will help in the long run.

Comment: All the 50 links have same ActionListner. The logic inside the ActionListner depends on the CommandLink clicked by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a listener and call the same listener on all of your command links. Inside the Listener Metod call `event.getAttributes()` which will return the Map of attributes. From the Map you can find the id property of the link submitted by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Simply attach an actionListener:

```
<af:commandLink text="Command link 1" actionListener="#{bean.link1}"/>
<af:commandLink text="Command link 2" actionListener="#{bean.link2}"/>
<af:commandLink text="Command link 3" actionListener="#{bean.link3}"/>
...
```

The methods `link1`, `link2`, `link3` etc. are called when you press the corresponding command link, so you implicitly know which link has been pressed.

Comment: What if I have 50 commandlinks? do you suggest by creating 50 different methods in the bean?

Comment: if the 50 command links do different operations then yes. If they all do same operation then why have 50 links? Or if the 50 links do the same operation but the data to be used in the operation is different then you can use <f:attribute> facet to pass that value and retrieve that attribute as: eventName.getComponent().getAttributes()

Comment: This might help. Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a listener in backing bean , listener method will have "ActionEvent" as an argument.
ActionEvent has apis getSource(),getComponent(), which can be leveraged to get the commandlink  clicked.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call 50 command link from backing bean,
you can queue them one after- see
[Invoking Button Action Programmatically,Queuing ActionEvent](http://oracleadf-java.blogspot.in/2013/04/invoking-button-action.html)